# What is a date (data type) in R and how to convert between different formats?

Tags: r

Given: Date presented as 30JUN03 stored in a column in a data frame.
It is also a factor in R.

How to convert 30JUN03 to 06-30-2003 ??? What function should I use?
After conversion how do I extract day month and year?

```
is.character(mydata$Date)
[1] FALSE
is.numeric(mydata$Date)
[1] FALSE
```

Help, please. MM

Comment: You can use `format(as.Date(mydata$Date, "%d%b%y"), '%m-%d-%Y')`

Comment: You might be interested in this blog post: https://michaeltoth.me/the-ultimate-opinionated-guide-to-base-r-date-format-functions.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? For questions that deal with data types, a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is necessary to give meaningful help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, then extract the 'year' and 'month' and later convert to 'Date' to the required format with `format`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mydata <- mydata %>%
           mutate(Date = dmy(Date), 
             year = year(Date),
             month = month(Date),
             Date = format(Date, '%m-%d-%Y'))
```

Comment: This is really neat code. It looks like I need a class in dplyr.  MM

Comment: @MaryA.Marion  Thanks, you can just do the assignment `mydata <- mydata %>%...`

Comment: I also have money variable which includes a $. I have been given a hint to go from money to character money to numeric money. SAS has character functions. Does R? I tried using dplyr with no success. Any hints here?

Comment: @MaryA.Marion  You can use `mydata %>% mutate(money = readr::parse_number(money))` i.e. `readr::parse_number("$568")
[1] 568`

Comment: mydata2$money2 = as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", mydata2$money)) worked for me. Your mutate code caused an error. Many thanks today. I was having a crash course in variable conversion code.  MM